# Java ASM java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I am new to Java ASM. I am trying to instrument methods using Java agent and ASM. But, I am getting error like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.FileOutputStream$1.<init>(Ljava/io/FileOutputStream;)V
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at WriteToFileExample.useFileWriter(WriteToFileExample.java:60)
    at WriteToFileExample.main(WriteToFileExample.java:30)
```

I am using asm-6.0.

I tried to write simple test code and it works. But, for some of the methods in some classes, it does not work. I do not understand why! ClassVisitor is visiting the class and then for all the methods, it accepts MethodVisitor. If no such method is existing in a class how it accepts visitor and why it is throwing exception?

Comment: The visitors are called according to the original code, *before* you make the changes that break the code.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I know that the visitors are called according to the test code. But, the method it says can't found is a method from the class it gets based on test code. Then, why no such method?

Comment: I have no idea what “*the method it says can't found is a method from the class it gets based on test code*” is supposed to mean. I start wondering what you are thinking, a) which method has not been found and b) which method is containing/causing the error…

Comment: I think I have figured it out. FileOutputStream$1 is an inner class of FileOutputStram. Using java agent, I was not getting information about FileOutputStream rather I was getting information about FileOutputStream$1. But, when visiting method, it says no such method found for init because there is no init method in FileOutputStream$1. Init method is in FileOutputStream. I changed java agent code to not to deal with the inner class but the actual FileOutputStream class and now it is fine.

Comment: the name `<init>` denotes a *constructor*. Of course, *both* classes have constructors. In case of an anonymous class, it’s a compiler generated constructor. Since the code works for everyone else, your agent must have *modified* the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. FileOutputStream$1 is an inner class of FileOutputStram. Using java agent, I was not getting information about FileOutputStream rather I was getting information about FileOutputStream$1. But, when visiting method, it says no such method found named init, also for some other methods as there is no init method in FileOutputStream$1. Init method is in FileOutputStream. I changed java agent code to not to deal with the inner class but the actual FileOutputStream class and now it is fine.